# Is it possible in iOS 6 to make banners only appear when the device is active, but self-dismiss upon unlock?

Tags: ios, settings, notifications, customization

If I'm using the device, I'd like to see banner notifications from other apps.

When I unlock it, I don't want a swarm of banner notifications bothering me and hindering my ability to use the top of whatever app I'm using. I'd rather just check the notification center at my leisure.

EDIT: But I still want the rest of the device to operate as per usual; in particular, I don't want to turn on Do Not Disturb b/c I want to be disturbed by whatever else I've set to disturb me.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is no....

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.  Turn on Do Not Disturb when you are in your phone.

Or just turn off notifications

http://www.imore.com/how-customize-notification-center-alerts-your-iphone-and-ipad

Comment: Good suggestion, but unfortunately not what I'm looking for. I still want to be disturbed, and still want the banner notifications to interrupt me while the device is unlocked, i.e. when I'm actually using it, just not to display a backlog of banner notifications after I haven't been using it.

Answer (score 1):

This actually is what has happened to my iphone 4s after updating to ios6. I used to have email notifications on banners and sound and if locked I would only hear the sound and when I unlocked I'ld get the banner flipping thru the emails I had recieved. After the update to Ios6 I here the sounds when it's locked but get no banners when I unlock. When I'm using it normally I get the banners as normal. This seems to be what you want I believe. I actually want it how it was. What ios are you running?

Comment: Unfortunately, 6 (as specified in title). Odd that the behavior is different for the two of us; I'm on iPhone 5 but I wouldn't expect Apple to implement notification behavior differently for the same OS on similar devices. I wonder if there is some other setting we have that is different? Do you do anything after hearing the sounds that might dismiss the notifications upon unlocking, or just hear them and ignore them?